GRUB 2.06 crashes on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot
I'm copying this from Reddit due to lack of help thus far. (please forgive me).
This has been an issue I have had for years, but when I first set up my dual boot I used GRUB, and I’ve now checked and found that it’s GRUB 2.06, and I had a dual boot of Win10 and Ubuntu (various versions, even tried Manjaro at one point, currently 22.04.3 LTS), but GRUB consistently would crash on boot and it was really annoying. My motherboard is an ASRock X570M Pro 4.
The details of the crash are as follows:
If I turn on the PC and GRUB crashes, what happens is when I press the down button on my keyboard, it inputs the down action once per frame and instantly reaches the bottom. If I then press Enter to boot up into the bottom option (Windows 10) - it just hangs on a black screen. If I do nothing and let it boot to the top option after the 6 second countdown or however long it is, it reaches the dreaded flashing cursor and hangs there. It does actually boot somewhat into Ubuntu because after trying a bunch of times and finally booting into Windows, my time is wrong (its set to UTC, my time zone is +10) and I have to change it back manually every time (automatically set the date actually seems to have UTC whitelisted so it just doesn't work).
This is a real issue because sometimes Windows likes to run updates on me without asking, and during the night will reboot. Of course, this results in a boot to GRUB, which crashes and then boots to the crashed Ubuntu (I don’t just unplug every USB port every night before going to bed you see). I've had this even interrupt calculations that were scheduled to take days and lost hours to days of work.
After countless trial and error, it seems that GRUB crashes every time if any of the USB3.2 ports have something connected to them (regardless of what that something may be) - and only some of the time if nothing is plugged into those ports.
I did ask elsewhere a couple years ago, but unfortunately the guy "helping" me was a total jerk, so I got nowhere. I'm asking here now since I'm fed up with this, it's such an unusual and cringe crash, booting my computer should never come down to RNG, and I want to know if any of you can help.
Note: The following paragraph I did receive help with, but I'm leaving it in since I haven't taken action on it yet due to the more pressing matters and would like to see any alternate options still:
Also does anyone know how I can perhaps change the options so that Windows is listed first? At least that way I don't have to reset the time every time it crashes in the future.

I mean sure I can upgrade it but these issues long predate any specific install of Ubuntu, so the version probably doesn’t matter. And if this is the wrong place, please please please direct me to a more appropriate place!! I’ve been searching and searching…

Have you checked for/applied any firmware updates for your motherboard?

Funny thing about that is I can’t seem to get the native motherboard software working… it comes up with read access violations.

Okay, I upgraded to 22.04.5 just to tick that box. Although it really scared me there, GRUB crashed 4 times in a row with no USB3.2 plugged in, I thought I’d bricked it for a hot minute there.

Okay, I have managed to locate an update for the BIOS on the ASRock website, although I can't quite make sense of the instructions and whether or not they apply to me. I think best bet would be to use 5.60 which is listed here, however I am unsure what the asterisks mean and the terminology is somewhat confusing. I know how incredibly risky this is, therefore I have uploaded what I believe to be the relevant portion of sysinfo here. Is someone able to assist (or is there a better place to ask for assistance)?

Search the read-only forums: https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=332 and try https://discourse.ubuntu.com/ for assistance and advice. The vendor site is another support option.
